# How to evaluate strings and use them as data names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables

What I would like to do is evaluate strings and convert them in data types like, 
If I have a string `x = "helloW"` and then read the value of `x` and make a list/function with the name `helloW` because the value of x is `helloW`. Suppose I have a file with many words and each line has a word and a number like:

```
lorem 1
ipsum 2
pac 3
heg 5
dis 7
```

Is there a way to make variables with name the words and value as numbers?

 We can use a for loop and int(), but how do we name the variables?
Is there any way to do so in python?

Comment: This is almost always not a good design choice, I highly suggest you don't do this

Comment: I'll tell you a secret, this is my first year in AOC , so I'm asking doubts related to solving puzzles from AOC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `global()` or a dictionary (code almost looks the same)

Creates variables

```
# directly create global vartiables
for every_line in input:
    var_name, var_value = every_line.split()
    globals()[var_name]=var_value
print(lorem, ipsum)
```

```
1 2
```

Creates a dictionary

```
my_variables = {} #empty dictionary
for every_line in input:
    var_name, var_value = every_line.split()
    my_variables[var_name]=var_value
print(my_variables)
```

```
{'lorem': '1', 'ipsum': '2', 'pac': '3', 'heg': '5', 'dis': '7'}
```

The pythonic way would be to use a dictionary!

`globals()` actually returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. That is why the code is so similar!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new variable, you can store the variables in a dictionary.

```py
vars = {}

for line in input:
    name, value = line.split(' ')
    vars[name] = int(value)
```

Now the dictionary `vars` will look like this.

```py
>>> vars
{'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 2, 'pac': 3, 'heg': 5, 'dis': 7}
```